# Using SQL Databse in Website using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, database, web-applications, web

Well, I have assigned a task to create a website which will compare two different products.
FOr that i have create a database which is having all the information about the products. What I have to do is that exactly , if a person choose a specification according to the choice all the products should be displayed on the particular webpage.

I have made the css file and everything on the website. Created the SQL database but dont know how to proceed to achieve my task.
Please help me out ASAP

Comment: You can also refer to this link to get started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581783.aspx Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems to me that ASAP questions are not for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should do some research on the following:

- Database Connection object
- Database Command object (which uses
  connection)
- DataReader Object (which uses command)

Pseudo Code

```
while readerObjectInstance.read
somevar = readerObjectInstance("dbcolumn").value
end while
```